# Removing bullets from ul, "list-style: none" not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists

I'm generating a ul with Wordpress' wp-nav-menu function, and can't seem to get the bullets to go away. I've tried all combinations of, using the id="menu-main-menu":

```
ul#menu-main-menu, ul#menu-main-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I've tried specifying the ul by class, and by ID, with no go. Tried the parent container for more specification, no go. I can't even style it inline as the HTML isn't rendered until the page is loaded.

Not sure what else to try. I'm pretty sure there's no conflicting CSS, as I'm working with a fresh stylesheet.

Comment: Inspect the element using Dev Tools to see if the styles are overridden - or maybe not applied at all. Also check your selectors. Is `ul#menu-main-menu` really correct?

Comment: you can always try and use the !important at the end like list-style: none !important;

Comment: ckear your cache and see if you have any cache plugin

Comment: That worked, boy do I feel stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Per Temani Afif, I cleared my browser's cache, and lo and behold, no more bullets. Thanks for the help everyone!

Pretty sure the id is correct. I'm too new to post a picture but here's a imgur link to what the inspector shows on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDm1h.jpg.

The id is automatically generated by Wordpress, it's not something I'd ever use.

I went back and couldn't find anything in the stylesheet, but here it is for some more savvy eyes to look over.

I added in !important, no dice.

```
html {

}

body {

}

.container {
    background-color: crimson;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    background-color: floralwhite;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.mainTitle {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.mainSection-container {
    background-color: dimgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contentRow-1 {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.menuSidebar {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #f4f2e5;
    padding: 10px;
    order: 2;
}

ul#menu-main-menu, ul#menu-main-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.todaysArticle {
    flex: 3;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 10px;
    order: 1;
}

.todaysArticle-text {

}

.todaysImage {

}

.dark-text-background {
    background-color: rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.56);
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.sidebar-2 {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #fff8e7;
    padding: 10px;
    order: 3;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .contentRow-1 {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .menuSidebar {
        order: 1;
    }
    .todaysArticle {
        order: 2;
    }
    .side-bar-2 {
        order: 3;
    }
}


.contentRow-2 {
    background-color: floralwhite;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.articleStub {
    background-color: #e6edf0;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.image {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.postSection {
    flex: 4;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 10px;
    order: 1;
}

.dummySpace {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    padding: 10px;
    order: 3;
}

.postImage {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .contentRow-1 {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .menuSidebar {
        order: 1;
    }
    .postSection {
        order: 2;
    }
    .dummySpace {
        order: 3;
    }
    .postImage {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
}

.authorSection {
    flex: 3;
    order: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}

.authorImage {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .contentRow-1 {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .menuSidebar {
        order: 1;
    }
    .authorSection {
        order: 2;
    }
    .authorImage {
        max-width: 600px;
    }
}
```